# my jquery animation function fails to work even when the call is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

may someone experienced with jquery and javascript please explain to me why this code does not work?
when changeclass is triggered, the image previmage should expand then decrease, but it doesn't seem to do either. The only thing that does work is the alert at the bottom.

any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeclass()
{
    if ($("#previmage").css({"max-width" : "400px"}){
        $("#previmage").animate({"max-width": "100%"}, "fast");
        $("#previmage").addClass("clicked").removeClass("normal");
    }else{
        $("#previmage").animate({"max-width": "400px"}, "fast");
        $("#previmage").addClass("normal").removeClass("clicked");       
    }
    alert("called");    
}
$("#progressBar").hide();
</script>
```

best regards
jordanzhninja

Comment: What is that condition supposed to do? Did you mean `if ($("#previmage").css("max-width") == 400)`?

Comment: it resizes an image when it is clicked, basically makes it larger

Comment: Please add your HTML code as well so we may better assist you

Comment: thank @Bergi (and the rest of StackOverflow) by accepting his answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if ($("#previmage").css({"max-width" : "400px"})
> ```

does *set* the `max-width` property and return the jQuery wrapper object which is always truthy. You need to use the [`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) as a getter and compare the result with the expected value:

```
if ($("#previmage").css("max-width") == 400)
```

However, I would recommend not to base your application logic on the css styles. Use a variable to save the state, or use classes (which can be tested with [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)) if you need/want to store it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

max width just allows the maximum width that is allowed for the particular class
if you want to increase the size of the image use width

```
if ($("#previmage").css({"width"}==400){
         $("#previmage").animate({width:"100%"}, "fast");
         $("#previmage").addClass("clicked").removeClass("normal");
        }
else{
             $("#previmage").animate({width: 400}, "fast");
             $("#previmage").addClass("normal").removeClass("clicked");

        }
```